# How to get a case class's 'copy' to use an overridden 'clone'?

Tags: scala

I suppose the obvious solution is to call `.clone.copy` everywhere, but there are certain applications where calling `.copy` without `.clone` might be dangerous or hard to debug.

This seems to [demonstrate](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/5ev2kq2/2) that `clone` (or the overridden `clone`), is not used by `copy`:

```
class Process {
  def replicate: Process = {
    println("Hello from Process.replicate")
    new Process()
  }
}

final case class Processes(
  process1: Process,
  process2: Process
) {
  override def clone: Processes = Processes(
    process1.replicate, process2.replicate)
}

val origProcesses = Processes(new Process, new Process)
val clonedProcesses = origProcesses.copy(process1 = new Process)
```

Comment: Look like it should not be case class

Comment: I could definitely get away with it not being a case class, thanks for the nudge, @cchantep ! This seems to work well: https://scalafiddle.io/sf/5ev2kq2/3 I will say it is a lot more boilerplate when you have a lot of class parameters, but, such is life sometimes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could provide your own copy method:

```
final case class Processes(
  process1: Process,
  process2: Process
) {
  override def clone: Processes = Processes(
    process1.replicate, process2.replicate)
  def copy(process1: Process = this.process1.replicate, process2: Process = this.process2.replicate): Processes = Processes(
    process1, process2)
}
```

In which case, you won't get the "free" `copy` method provided by Scala, but you can still avoid implementing your own `equals`, `hashCode` and companion object `apply`, `unapply` etc.

Comment: I have to admit, this should have been obvious to me, but I had forgotten about the magic of default arguments for a moment, and thus was thinking that case classes' 'copy' was itself "magical" at the implementation level.

Comment: I guess the other tricky bit was that you don't need to override copy, but I should have pieced that together from other google searches.

Comment: That's true. I just had the compiler yell at me for the `override` keyword, and removed it. And then when I thought about it, it made sense, so I just let it be. :-D